# How to insert/modify/remove license headers in the source code from multiple languages

Tags: c++, python, ruby-on-rails, licensing, jenkins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for adding license headers to source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151677/tool-for-adding-license-headers-to-source-files)

We have legacy code built using C++, ruby-on-rails and scripts in sh, python. Are there any plug-ins which will allow you to insert license copyright headers (`add/modify/remove`) seamlessly across files in the above languages

Comment: It is not the exact copy. He also wants to modify or remove

Comment: @Als - I don't want language specific solutions to manipulate my license headers. Ideally if I can control the logic using a single tool / plug-in it would be useful

Comment: Requesting reopen, since the tools in that questions are not allowing changing or removing the licence text. They are only adding licence text to the top of the files.

Comment: Would like to re-open as I feel my question hasn't been answered yet. I am looking for a solution much similar to maven-license-plugin and I would just see the above source code as files and I need the flexibility to add/modify/remove