# tool or vbscript to add hardcoded text to top of multiple files?

Tags: scripting, vbscript

Does anyone know a tool that can add predefined text such as the following 4 lines:

```
"My disclaimer:
For legal reasons -
1. Don't blah...
2. You must..."
```

to all .txt files in a directory: "C:/test/"

I have seen append functions but they only add to the bottom, not sure of a method for adding to the top of the file.

My OS is Win XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but it should put you on the right track.

```
Dim FSO, txs, fld, fil, content
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set fld = FSO.GetFolder("C:\test\")
For Each fil In fld.Files
    If Right(fil.Name, 3) = "txt" Then

        Set txs = fil.OpenAsTextStream(1) ' 1 = for reading
        content = txs.ReadAll
        txs.Close

        Set txs = fil.OpenAsTextStream(2) ' 2 = for writing
        txs.Write "MyDisclaimer:" & vbCrLf & "stuff" & content
        txs.Close

    End If    
Next
```

Comment: Set fld = FSO.GetFolder("C:\test\") - For Each fil In fld.Files

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but the fld.Files is necessary too.

Comment: Slowly getting there... There.

Comment: when i run this in a text editor it gives me error: "(17, 6) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement" but if i run it from excel it is fine. ??

Comment: just had to make it Next not Next fil

Comment: Right... VBA accepts that, but not VBScript. Sorry for the mix-up; corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

[SrcHead](http://www.solvasoft.nl/downloads.html) is a free utility that can adjust the header of multiple sourcefiles. It is written for Windows and needs the .NET Framework 2.0 to work.

Comment: You can also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151677/tool-for-adding-license-headers-to-source-files