# How can I add a block of text to all the PHP files in all subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command

I have a PHP script that I need to add my copyright into at the top.  I simply want it to appear after

Here's what needs to be added:

```
/**
 * MySoftware
 *
 * This file is part of MySoftware.
 *
 * MySoftware is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * MySoftware is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with MySoftware.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright MySoftware
 * @license     GNU Public License V3.0
*/
```

It would be great if a blank line could be added before and after the above message so that it stands out more in each file if possible.

What would be the fastest way to add this to the top of all my php files?  There are several hundred and I've moved them all into one main folder/subfolders so I was thinking that something could be recursively run with command line to add this to the top of each.

If anyone could post a sample script/code of how to do this via command line or any other method, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please note that what you are asking to do breaks down to two distinct tasks: Finding all PHP files recursively under the directory, and adding a block of text to the top of the file.

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151677/tool-for-adding-license-headers-to-source-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your text into a file, say `/tmp/header`, then run the following script.

```
DIR=/your/php/files/dir
for f in $(find ${DIR} -iname "*.php" -type f 2>/dev/null) ; do
    cat /tmp/header "${f}" > /tmp/tmp_file || continue
    /bin/mv /tmp/tmp_file "${f}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
text="Hello world
What's up?"

exec 3<> $1 && awk -v TEXT="$text" 'BEGIN {print TEXT}{print}' $1 >&3
```

Try that.

Comment: What would I need to change with that so it applies to all PHP files?  It looks like that's for one specific file...

Comment: find . -name '*php' -print | xargs -J% sh /from/the/revised/answer