# How to add automatic signature to code files?

Tags: vim, code-signing, gedit

Many code files available on the internet contain signatures. Author, Company, Date Created, Last Edit, Sometimes a drawn symbol too and a description of license or whatever this is called.

Is there a way to create this in common text editors? Vim or Gedit for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool for adding license headers to source files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151677/tool-for-adding-license-headers-to-source-files)

Comment: Do you want to add a header to existing files which are missing it, or pre-populate newly created files with the header?

Comment: @Ben I would like both if possible, But the priority is for pre-populating newly created files of course.

Comment: @RandyMorris please post that as an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `:help skeleton` for a primitive way of doing this. It won't leave you placeholders that you can jump to or anything, for that you'd be better off with a snippet plugin. Skeletons are usually good enough for this sort of thing.